# Energy dissipation from a black hole by neutrinos

Tags: black-holes, neutrinos, superfluidity

Could the high gravitation field of a black hole cause neutrinos to form a Fermi gas or superfluid?  Could these neutrinos from the neutrino background of the big bang whose temperature and deBroglie wavelength could cause neutrino wave functions to overlap form a Fermi gas or superfluid?  Various excitations of a superfluid such as phonons or rotons could escape the halo surrounding the black hole event horizon or maybe simple scattering of neutrinos from the lower filled states may be sufficient to dissipate energy.  Is this too far fetched an idea?

Another dissipation mechanism may also be possible via muon or kaon creation...

https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2018/06/180605172508.htm